# How to change response before send

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish

Is it possible to intercept sending response to client, and send modified response in final ?
I want to remove "WWW-Authenticate" header from Basic Auth response or change error code from 401 to 403 in wrong authentication case.
P.S. I have the same problem: http://www.java.net/forum/topic/glassfish/glassfish/suppress-www-authenticate-header-if-basic-auth-fails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried use Filter with HttpServletResponseWrapper but my Filter was never called before JAAS Basic HTTP Authentication. I solved my problems with annoying popup window by next code

In web.xml:

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>401</error-code>
    <location>/error.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

error.jsp:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <%
        int status = response.getStatus();
        if (status == 401) {
            response.setStatus(403);
        }
        %>
    </body>
</html>
```