# Avoid basic auth popup when querying rest-backend application from frontend application

Tags: java, reactjs, ajax, glassfish, basic-authentication

I have two applications, two wars, app-rest and app-web. App-rest is the backend holding a rest-api and app-web is the frontend holding a react GUI.

I want to secure the backend using basic auth but when doing this the frontend ajax requests trigger a basic auth popup in the browser.

I am using Glassfish as an application server.

I have tried securing both applications in hopes of them sharing the session cookie but that does not seem to be the case.

Also tried java filters to try and remove WWW-authenticate header when unauthorized since I have read that that header is the one triggering the popup, but filters are not activated during basic auth initialization.

I have tried using form-based login and that kind of works but then I loose the ability to use applications like postman to test my rest-api (at least I think this is the case since I cant authenticate in the request itself)

How can I avoid showing the basic auth popup when doing requests from the frontend to the backend ?

Comment: I think the authentication form is meant to work in a web application where a human will provide credentials in the authentication process, and in this case the web service is meant to interact between applications so I'm not sure using the authentication in this case to secure the back end is the right approach. Probably the following can help: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24983/secure.htm#RESTF113

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This wonderful human being solved it: [How to change response before send](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10158877/how-to-change-response-before-send)

What he did was to add this to the web.xml

```
<error-page>
   <error-code>401</error-code>
   <location>/error.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

And in error.jsp:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
            <title></title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <%
            int status = response.getStatus();
            if (status == 401) {
                response.setStatus(403);
            }
            %>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Then in your javascript you can just look for status code 403 and show a custom login screen without basic auth popup.